# Редко отображается реклама AdMob

Tags: android, admob

Добавил в свое приложение межстраничную рекламу с Admob. Делал всё по этой инструкции: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#helpful_resources

Первую неделю всё хорошо работало, реклама появлялась после каждого клика раз в минуту. Но теперь надо раз 50 нажать на одну кнопку, чтобы появилась реклама.

Кто сталкивался? Что делать?

Comment: Добавьте исходного кода, где и что не получается. Вопрос не информативен. Правильно поставленный вопрос - это уже часть ответа.

Comment: Дело в том, что код когда все работало и код когда работает редко тот же самый. @DenisBubnov

Comment: вот уж не знаю как помочь разобраться в этом...

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.